Dioxus Router Error: use navigation doesnt work
I'm working on a project using Dioxus with routing. My problem occurs when trying to navigate to a different route in my component (src/pages/home.rs). I'm getting the following router-related
use crate::api::alpha_vantage::{AlphaVantageClient, StockData};
use dioxus::prelude::*;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct SearchResult {
    #[serde(rename = "1. symbol")]
    symbol: String,
    #[serde(rename = "2. name")]
    name: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct SearchResponse {
    #[serde(rename = "bestMatches")]
    best_matches: Vec<SearchResult>,
}

#[component]
pub fn HomePage() -> Element {
    rsx! {
        SearchComponent {}
    }
}

#[component]
fn SearchComponent() -> Element {
    let mut search_query = use_signal(|| String::new());
    let mut search_results = use_signal(|| Vec::<SearchResult>::new());
    let navigator = use_navigator();

    // TODO: add debouncer
    let _ = use_resource(move || async move {
        let query = search_query();
        if !query.is_empty() {
            match search_stocks(query.clone()).await {
                Ok(results) => search_results.set(results),
                Err(_) => search_results.set(Vec::new()),
            }
        }
    });
    let on_select_symbol = |symbol: &str| {
        // Navigate to ticker page with the selected symbol
        navigator.push(Route::TickerPage {
            symbol: symbol.to_string(),
        });
    };

    rsx! {
        div { class: "min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center bg-gray-100",
            div { class: "bg-white shadow-lg rounded-lg p-8 max-w-lg w-full",
                h1 { class: "text-4xl font-bold text-center text-gray-800", "Welcome to Stock Sage" }
                p { class: "text-lg text-gray-600 text-center mt-4", "Search for a stock symbol to get started" }

                div { class: "mt-6",
                    input {
                        class: "w-full p-3 border rounded-lg text-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500",
                        placeholder: "Search for a stock symbol",
                        oninput: move |evt| search_query.set(evt.value()),
                        value: "{search_query}"
                    }
                }
                if !search_results().is_empty() {
                    div {
                        class: "mt-4 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md overflow-hidden",
                        for result in search_results().iter() {
                            div {
                                class: "p-3 border-b hover:bg-gray-100 cursor-pointer",
                                onclick: move |_| on_select_symbol(&result.symbol),
                                h2 { class: "font-bold", "{result.symbol}" }
                                p { class: "text-gray-600", "{result.name}" }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

async fn search_stocks(query: String) -> Result<Vec<SearchResult>, reqwest::Error> {
    let client = AlphaVantageClient::new();
    let url = format!(
        "{}?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords={}&apikey={}",
        crate::api::alpha_vantage::BASE_URL,
        query,
        client.api_key
    );

    let response: SearchResponse = client.client.get(&url).send().await?.json().await?;
    Ok(response.best_matches)
}

my main.rs looks like this
#![allow(non_snake_case)]

use dioxus::prelude::*;
use dioxus_logger::tracing::{info, Level};

use stock_sage::pages::{home::HomePage, ticker::TickerPage};

#[derive(Routable, Clone, Debug, PartialEq)]
#[rustfmt::skip]
pub enum Route {
    #[layout(NavBar)]
        #[route("/")]
        HomePage {},
        #[route("/ticker/:symbol")]
        TickerPage { symbol: String },
    #[end_layout]
    #[route("/:..route")]
    PageNotFound {
        route: Vec<String>,
    },
}

fn main() {
    dotenv::dotenv().ok();
    // Init logger
    dioxus_logger::init(Level::INFO).expect("failed to init logger");
    info!("starting app");

    let cfg = dioxus::desktop::Config::new()
        .with_custom_head(r#"<link rel="stylesheet" href="tailwind.css">"#.to_string());
    LaunchBuilder::desktop().with_cfg(cfg).launch(App);
}

#[component]
fn App() -> Element {
    rsx! {
        Router::<Route> {}
    }
}

#[component]
fn NavBar() -> Element {
    rsx! {
        nav {
            class: "bg-blue-500 p-4",
            ul {
                li {
                    Link { to: Route::HomePage {}, class: "text-white mr-4", "Home" }
                    Link { to: Route::TickerPage { symbol: "AAPL".to_string() }, "Apple Stock" }
                }
            }
        }
        Outlet::<Route> {}
    }
}

#[component]
fn PageNotFound(route: Vec<String>) -> Element {
    rsx! {
        h1 { "Page not found" }
        p { "We are terribly sorry, but the page you requested doesn't exist." }
        pre { color: "red", "log:\nattempted to navigate to: {route:?}" }
    }
}




#![allow(non_snake_case)]

use dioxus::prelude::*;
use dioxus_logger::tracing::{info, Level};

use stock_sage::pages::{home::HomePage, ticker::TickerPage};

#[derive(Routable, Clone, Debug, PartialEq)]
#[rustfmt::skip]
pub enum Route {
    #[layout(NavBar)]
        #[route("/")]
        HomePage {},
        #[route("/ticker/:symbol")]
        TickerPage { symbol: String },
    #[end_layout]
    #[route("/:..route")]
    PageNotFound {
        route: Vec<String>,
    },
}

fn main() {
    dotenv::dotenv().ok();
    // Init logger
    dioxus_logger::init(Level::INFO).expect("failed to init logger");
    info!("starting app");

    let cfg = dioxus::desktop::Config::new()
        .with_custom_head(r#"<link rel="stylesheet" href="tailwind.css">"#.to_string());
    LaunchBuilder::desktop().with_cfg(cfg).launch(App);
}

#[component]
fn App() -> Element {
    rsx! {
        Router::<Route> {}
    }
}

#[component]
fn NavBar() -> Element {
    rsx! {
        nav {
            class: "bg-blue-500 p-4",
            ul {
                li {
                    Link { to: Route::HomePage {}, class: "text-white mr-4", "Home" }
                    Link { to: Route::TickerPage { symbol: "AAPL".to_string() }, "Apple Stock" }
                }
            }
        }
        Outlet::<Route> {}
    }
}

#[component]
fn PageNotFound(route: Vec<String>) -> Element {
    rsx! {
        h1 { "Page not found" }
        p { "We are terribly sorry, but the page you requested doesn't exist." }
        pre { color: "red", "log:\nattempted to navigate to: {route:?}" }
    }
} 

cargo.toml

dioxus = { version = "0.5", features = ["desktop", "router"] }

# Debug
dioxus-logger = "0.5.1"

Code works fine but problems is mainly with the router i have no idea why it is not working should i export router enum or what ?
Info from cargo check:
failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `Route`
  --> src/pages/home.rs:45:24
   |
45 |         navigator.push(Route::TickerPage {
   |                        ^^^^^ use of undeclared type `Route`
   |
help: there is an enum variant `crate::pages::home::IntoRoutable::Route` and 1 other; try using the variant's enum
   |
45 |         navigator.push(crate::pages::home::IntoRoutable {
   |                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
45 |         navigator.push(dioxus::prelude::IntoRoutable {
   |                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.
warning: `stock-sage` (lib) generated 4 warnings


Please [edit] your question to include the full error message from cargo check (not from your IDE).

@Jmb i added the check message
